# Слово "монашество" в значении монашеское братство - возможно ли?

Tags: выбор-слов

> В тяжёлые для Рима времена – с 387 до 1084 года, когда Рим был взят и
>   разграблен семь раз, Монти застраивается оборонительными сооружениями.
>   Вокруг древних домов и новых **монашеств** вырастают стены, внутри
>   которых поднимаются высокие донжоны. Одна из таких сохранившихся
>   цитаделей – храм Четырёх венценосных мучеников / Santi Quattro
>   Coronati.

В названии храма не три ли слова с прописной?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Большой Энциклопедический словарь**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc3p/201842):
**МОНАШЕСТВО** (от греч. *monachos* - отшельник - монах), *социальная религиозная **группа,*** члены которой берут на себя обязательства: "уход из мира"; как правило, отказ от имущества; воздержание (обязательно безбрачие); разрыв старых родственных и социальных связей; ***прикрепление к монастырю***, подчинение его уставу.

[**Современная энциклопедия**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc1p/30930/%D0%9C%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%A8%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%92%D0%9E):
**МОНАШЕСТВО** (от греческого *monachos* - живущий в одиночестве, уединенно), *объединение верующих (группа, община, братство)*...

Получается, что можно так говорить: *вокруг монашеств*.

Храм *Santi Quattro Coronati* — думаю (при дословном переводе названия), вполне допустимы все три слова с прописной:  *храм Четырёх Венценосных Мучеников.*

Храм Трёх Святителей, церковь Четырех Евангелистов, часовня Трех Святителей, церковь Сорока Мучеников Севастийских.

Comment: Пусть даже МОНАШЕСТВО - община верующих. Стены-то вырастали не вокруг общин, а вокруг мест их поселения. Я бы поостерегся.

Answer (score 1):

МОНАШЕСТВО, -а; ср. 1. Монашеская жизнь, пребывание в монашеском чине. Принять м. Обет монашества. 2. **собир. Монахи**. 3. Разг. Об уединенном, аскетическом образе жизни кого-л.

Вокруг древних домов и новых монашеств вырастают стены... Только как  **окказионализм** (индивидуально-авторский неологизм).